# JavaScript Division on floating returns strange result

Tags: javascript, division

I am building a [Metrics Converter](https://www.metricsconverter.com/) site where precise calculations matter a lot and I noticed a strange issue when performing these metrics calculations.

Let me post a few instances which I have come across and any solution would be appreciated.

I have a Centimeter to Meter Conversion Page where I take the user input and divide by 100 to get the meter output. It works properly except for a few strange numbers.

Eg - 0.009 cm would be 0.00009 Meters

The formula used would be 0.009/100 = 0.00009 Meters

However, JavaScript returns a weird result

1. 0.009/100 returns as 0.00008999999999999999
2. 0.007/100 returns as 0.00007000000000000001
3. 0.00009/100 returns as 9.000000000000001e-7

The same can be verified in the console or on the website [cm to meters](https://www.metricsconverter.com/length/centimeters-to-meters/) also by providing the centimeter value.

Now the site requires precise calculations for these metrics/units it would be a bad experience to use if it displays a strange result with long numbers. I am sure that it will happen with many other floating point numbers and other conversion formulas that is been used.

I have noticed the same is not happening in Python, C# language as it returns accurately.

**Any solutions or workaround is appreciated to solve this issue**

Comment: Actually, the same happens with Python
`print(0.009/100 == 0.00008999999999999999)  # True`
`print(0.007/100 == 0.00007000000000000001)  # True`
`print(0.00009/100 == 9.000000000000001e-7)  # True`

`print(0.009/100 == 0.00009)  # False`
`print(0.007/100 == 0.00007)  # False`
`print(0.00009/100 == 9e-7)  # False`

Comment: I believe i need to use a parseFloat function with `toFixed()` which solves the issue.

`parseFloat((0.009/100).toFixed(10))`